# how to Passing headers and body at a time in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

**Im sending 2 headers and a body of class type here**

```
 @POST("/api/access/change-password")
    Call<JsonElement> changePassword(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type,
    @Header("Authorization") String AuthToken,
    @Body PostChangePassword postChangePassword);
```

here i am posting the data to server. but it returns some error. It is working fine in postman. but not in here.

```
public void postData(String old_password, String new_password) {
    Log.v("im here in retro0", "");
    PostChangePassword postChangePassword = new PostChangePassword(sharedPrefUserData.getUserData().getUserId(), sharedPrefUserData.getUserData().getAuthToken(), old_password, new_password);
    mAPIService.changePassword("application/json", "Bearer " + sharedPrefUserData.getUserData().getAuthToken(), postChangePassword).enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
            Log.v("im here in retro1", response + "");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                JsonElement jsonElement = response.body();
                if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                    JsonObject objectWhichYouNeed = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                    ResponseChangePassword object = gson.fromJson(objectWhichYouNeed, ResponseChangePassword.class);

                }
            } else {
                Log.v("im here in retro2", response + "");
                ResponseChangePassword responseChangePassword = null;
                try {
                    responseChangePassword = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string(), ResponseChangePassword.class);
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, responseChangePassword.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
            //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            internetConnectionChecker.serverErrorAlert();
            Log.v("im here in retro3", "");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you show the error

Comment: No error. The data im passing are not sending to server with headers. But others are working fine with posting  body.